# How does the python determine the appropriate metaclass?

Tags: python, grammar, cpython

I maybe find the answer in [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#determining-the-appropriate-metaclass), but I still can not get it. Can you give me a more detailed or straight forward explanation in the second and third case? I will appreciate it if you could give me some examples!

> The appropriate metaclass for a class definition is determined as follows:
>
> - if no bases and no explicit metaclass are given, then `type()` is used;
> - if an explicit metaclass is given and it is *not* an instance of type(), then it is used directly as the metaclass;
> - if an instance of `type()` is given as the explicit metaclass, or bases are defined, then the most derived metaclass is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's think you trying to implement the pattern of Singleton by a metaclass (in this case by two of them).

```
class Singleton(type):
    _inst = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return cls._inst.setdefault(cls, super().__call__(*args, **kwargs))

class Singleton2(Singleton):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)



class SingletonClass1(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass


class SingletonClass2(SingletonClass1, metaclass=Singleton2):
    pass


class SingletonClass3():
    pass


class SingletonClass4(SingletonClass2, metaclass=Singleton):
    pass
```

`type(class_obj)` function returns the metaclass of `class_obj`.

So here's your cases:

1. if no bases and no explicit metaclass are given, then type() is used;

   `type(SingletonClass3) --> <class 'type'>`

<s>2. if an explicit metaclass is given and it is not an instance of type(), then it is used directly as the metaclass;</s>

```
`type(SingletonClass2) --> <class '__main__.Singleton2'>`
```

3. if an instance of type() is given as the explicit metaclass, or bases are defined, then the most derived metaclass is used;

```
`type(SingletonClass4) --> <class '__main__.Singleton2'>`
```

If you inherit SingletonClass2 from SingletonClass1 but forget to inherit Singleton2 from Singleton, it'll cause TypeError.

> The most derived metaclass is one which is a subtype of all of these
>   candidate metaclasses. If none of the candidate metaclasses meets that
>   criterion, then the class definition will fail with TypeError.

**Update:**
Metaclasses can be functions, that are not instances of `type`, so the second case (*if an explicit metaclass is given and it is not an instance of type*) can be related to this. Here's Singleton implementation by a metaclass function.

```
def singleton_func(class_name, bases, attrs):
    _inst = {}

    def custom_new(cls):
        return _inst.setdefault(cls, object.__new__(cls))

    attrs['__new__'] = custom_new
    return type(class_name, bases, attrs)


class SingletonClass5(metaclass=singleton_func):
    pass
```

Comment: Why does the doc say "instance of type() is given as the explicit metaclass" instead of "subclass of type() ......" . I mean that the most of user-defined classes are "instance of type()", Could a class not inheriting from `type` be a metaclass?

Comment: Updated answer based on this comment, is it covers your question?

Comment: Just one more thing... If I have a metaclass defined as `class  Singleton3(type, metaclass=Singleton)`. Is it a case for the second case?

Comment: I think the third because an instance of type() is given as the explicit metaclass.